# How does drupal.org save users' locations?

Tags: 7, location

On Drupal.org, when you go to the user profile edit page, there is an option:

**Save my location**

*Your location will be saved and may be shared.*

How is this implemented?  Is this through a contributed module(s), or is this something specific to d.o?

Comment: It *looks* to be using the HTML5  https://drupal.org/project/geolocation module

Comment: (FYI: Pre Drupal 7, drupal.org used these modules/themes:  https://drupal.org/node/27367 and hopefully they'll update the list soon)